# how to use http server and socket connection together

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using http server with socket connection response of http request goes when client responds to socket connection i am currently doing it by storing `res` in a global object which i think is not a correct method, what is the correct method to do it.

```
const app = require('express')()
bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json())
const net = require('net');
var client;
var res1,currentReq;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// http requests listener
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

app.listen(8001, () => console.log('Http server listening on port 8001'));

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// http requests handling
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

app.post('/makeCall', (req, res) => {
        console.log('sd' + req.body)
        res1 = res;
        currentReq='makeCall';
        client.write("something");

});

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Establishing tcp connection for incoming requests
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

var server = net.createServer(function(connection) {
   console.log ('client has connected successfully!');
   client = connection;
   client.on('data',function(data){
   switch(currentReq) 
   {
       case 'makeCall' :
                    res1.end(data);
                    break;
   }

  });
});


//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// listener for tcp connections
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

server.listen(8000, function() {
   console.log('server for localhost is listening on port 8000');
});
```

Comment: You are correct. There are better ways to do this but it might depend on the purpose of your TCP connection. Can you give more information on what the TCP connection is for?

Comment: i am using it to connect it to a client whose ip is not public, when http request hits on server it sends a message to client which processes the request (like database query and another http request) and sends the message back to server.

Comment: It's not clear to me why there needs to be 2 ports. Have you considered websockets? If you use websockets, you can share cookies, allowing you to store data in the cookie, such as `currentReq` or the ID of the user/browser. WebSockets allow full duplex exchange of data, much like (but not exactly the same as) a TCP connection. Is this something that would work for you?

Comment: i will try this method can you link me a tutorial using http and socket connection together

Comment: The most popular library is [`socket.io`](https://socket.io/). There is a [chat tutorial](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/) but maybe it's easier if I try to give an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our discussion in comments, here is an example of how one might do this using [`socket.io`](https://socket.io/).

Using a `socket.io` set-up, the browser will connect to the HTTP server to make HTTP `GET` AND `POST` requests, e.g. to `/makeCall`. The browser will also connect to the *same* HTTP server to open the socket. The browser will connect by HTTP initially, then send a special handshake which will convert the connection into a WebSocket.

I still am not sure to understand your use case so perhaps this solution is not appropriate, but here is the general setup of what it might look like.

```
const app = require('express')()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session')

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cookieSession({
  keys: ['secret key', 'another one', 'a third one'],
  maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 // cookie max-age : 24 hours
}))


//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// http requests listener
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
server.listen(8001, () => console.log('Http server listening on port 8001'));
// WARNING: app.listen() will NOT work here! per socket.io docks

const idToSocketMap = new Map();

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// http requests handling
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
app.post('/makeCall', (req, res) => {
  console.log('sd' + req.body)
  if (!req.session.id) {
    req.session.id = generateId();
  }

  //this may not be necessary, see below
  req.session.currentReq = 'makeCall';

  const socket = idToSocketMap.get(req.session.id)
  if (socket) { //if a socket connected for that id
    socket.emit("makeCall", "an argument/parameter", "something");
  }
});

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Establishing websocket connection for incoming requests
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  //"socket" is now what would have been called "client" in old code

  //get the id from the session cookie of the http request
  const id = socket.request.session.id;
  //put the socket in the map
  idToSocketMap.set(id, socket);
  //remove the socket from the map on disconnect
  socket.on('disconnect', () => idToSocketMap.delete(id));

  console.log('client has connected successfully!');

  socket.on('makeCall', (firstParameter, something) => {
    // It's still not possible to send anything back to an HTTP connection
    // but we may do some things and reply here
    const someData = getSomeData();
    socket.emit('makeCallResponse', 'someData');
  });
});
```